Read and write file tags with URLResourecKey.tagNamesKey on iOS
URLResourecKey.tagNamesKey is only available on macOS, so apparently there's no way of reading or writing file tags on iOS. Why is this the case, given that file tags can be set via Finder on macOS and the Files app on iOS devices? Is there a workaround?
